# Merging excel cells based on the cell value using c#

Tags: c#, excel, merge, cells

I am using excel with c# I want to merge all adjacent cells that contain a specific value using c# code.

I want to merge all the cells that contains the value (Merged cells) using c# code
[image: Excel Sheet]

i want it to be like this

[image]

Comment: what technology are you using to read/write Excel file?

Comment: I am using Microsoft office library (Interop)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify the cells where the range of repetitive value starts and where it ends.

Then, use this code to merge the cells:

```
String startRange = "A1";
String endRange = "D3";
String repetitiveValue = "Merged Cells";
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = worksheet.Range[startRange, endRange];
range.Value2 = repetitiveValue;
range.Select();
range.Merge(Missing.Value);
```

Comment: But what if i don't know the range of the repetitive values

Comment: There is no direct solution to automatically merge repetitive values. You must search for this kind of ranges.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one or the other Office library, which can help you with reading/writing spreadsheets & also with the cell merges.
Check SpreadSheetGear.net or PowerTools for OpenXml (for >= office 2007 formats)
http://ericwhite.com/blog/powertools-for-open-xml-expanded/